# Which elements of $su(n)$ commute with those of a subalgebra $su(2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

Given a subalgebra $su(2) \subset su(n)$ , how many generators of $su(n)$ commute with any element in the subalgebra $su(2)$?

I know that there are at least $n-2$ elements in $su(n)$ satisfying this property. Those are the independent generators of the Cartan subalgebra of $su(n)$ (whose dimension is $n-1$) that are not elements of the subalgebra $su(2)$.

But, are there more possibilities?

Comment: With this posts and with future posts on this site, you should show your work (or any work that you've done) so that answerers know what to emphasize and what to skip.

Comment: (For example, the bit about how we have at least the Cartan subalgebra is worth adding to the question).  Some questions about your question: what do you mean by "a subalgebra $su_2$"?  Do you mean any subalgebra of $su_n$ that is isomorphic to $su_2$, or do you mean some canonical presentation?  And what do you mean by "how many generators"?  Do you have some canonical list of generators of $su_n$ that you're talking about?

Comment: Thank you for the advice, as you can see I'm new here.

By "a subalgebra $su(2)$ I mean any subalgebra of su(n) isomorphic to su(2).

Regarding your other question, I'll try to be more precise: How many independent elements $x_i \in su(n)$ commute with any element of that subalgebra?